# Class method inline definitions

Tags: c++, c++11

I find it a very appealing programming style define all the methods of a struct/class directly inline in the struct, eg only define structs this way:

```
"A.hpp"
class A;

"A.cpp"
class A
{
    A() = default;
    void method() { }
};
```

rather than

```
"A.hpp"
class A
{
    A();
    void method();
};

"A.cpp"
A::A() = default;
void A::method() { }
```

This means putting classes/struct definitions in a code file and only including declaration in header files.

However, this runs into the problems when the compiler would need to know the struct/class layout in other code files.

Is there a programming style that supports this? Perhaps only getting and setting fields through getters/setters? This way would however lead to large amounts of boilerplate.

Just including the struct/class definition in the header file leads to issues with mutually recursive header files, unless one explicitly puts the declarations in another.

I can achieve this programming style in a language like D with a module system, but how does one achieve it in C++?

Comment: To use a class, the compiler needs to know what variables it contains (to determine its size), and what member functions it has (so it can generate symbols for linking).  Therefore, the class definition must always be visible in any file that actually uses that class (i.e. does pretty much anything other than declaring a pointer or reference to it).  While your idea is a valid option (albeit one that can potentially slow compilation and/or make the class' definition look messy), you're doing it wrong if you put the class' definition in a source file.

Comment: C++ compilation model makes what you are trying to do impossible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to do what OP desires.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing is called forward declaration.

You will be not able to do anything (f.e. call methods, create instances) with this class in all other translation units, except one .cpp file, where you define it. So, this idea is completely useless and bad. And you will get a boatload of linker errors.

So, you need to either stick to style #2. Or define inline methods in header file, like this

```
struct A {
    A() {} // something
    int func() { /* function body */
}
```

Comment: I think you misinterpretted the question. I understand the technical reasons WHY I can't do this, why question is how can I work around this.

Comment: @sprw121 there is no way to do it like you want.
Probably, you can create another header, put whole class definition, and include it in original header. But this is still ugly